# jupyter notebook: interrupt after full episode

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interrupt, reinforcement-learning

I have a reinforcement learning model which is trained in a for loop.
the training part is like this:

```
for episode in range(1, max_episodes + 1):
    print(f"episode: {episode}. RAM usage: {process_memory()/1024/1024} MB")
    this_state = trading_environment.reset()
    for episode_step in range(max_episode_steps):
        action = ddqn.epsilon_greedy_policy(this_state.reshape(-1, state_dim))
        next_state, reward, done, _ = trading_environment.step(action)
    # more codes
trading_environment.close()
```

Is there a way to interrupt the training but let it keep running until a full episode is finished?
Currently it stops at a random step in an episode, leaving an incomplete episode.

Comment: The simplest approach might be to write checkpoints at each episode so that you keep your progress when interrupting. You can catch a keyboard interrupt signal with a Try/Except block as well, but the logic to allow an episode to finish before killing the program might be tricky.

Comment: @MikeL If you mean `saving tensorflow sequential model` by writing checkpoints, I've implemented it. The problem is that since model size and episode number are huge, I write checkpoints for every 50 episodes. That means if I interrupt the training at 145 episodes, the last 45 episodes are not saved and could be corrupted by early termination. Do you have any idea solving this problem?

Comment: Hmm, I see. Do you need early checkpoints? Can you delete the oldest checkpoint each time you write a new one? This might make more frequent checkpointing viable since you won't burn through disk space

Comment: @MikeL With `10k episodes` * `500MB checkpoint per episode on average`, that's 6TB data to write. Could that be a burden for a 1TB SSD? I think that's inefficient. What I try now is to manually erase recent changes in the agent object, so that the incomplete data don't go into the checkpoint. Do you see any problem this way?

Comment: Yeah I see why deleting is useful, but why manually? My previous post's idea was to delete with Python. Might save a lot of time

Comment: To be more concrete, can you delete your previous checkpoint with a line of python each time you write a new checkpoint? Then your disk usage is constant and you get finer granularity on your checkpoints

Comment: @MikeL You are right, I mean programmatically. I have another idea. By wrapping an episode training into a function, will interruption wait until that function finishes?

Comment: I bet you could make that work if you catch the keyboard interrupt error

Comment: @MikeL This sounds promising. Could you please explain a bit more?